# how to select target tag with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Hello everybody and thanks for reading.

I have this html;

```
<i class="icon-plus icon-white"> Test 1</i>
```

How can i select this with jquery and change the "icon-plus" in "icon-minus" and replace the text "Test 1" into something else?

Comment: thanks all for the advice for me this works   $('i').toggleClass('icon-plus').toggleClass('icon-minus');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bGwrS/31/)

```
$(".icon-plus").removeClass("icon-plus").addClass("icon-minus").html("new text");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
$("i").removeClass('icon-plus').addClass('icon-minus');
$("i").html("Some Text");
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is the only tag `<i>` then you could use:

```
$("i").removeClass("icon-plus").addClass("icon-minus").html([your html])
```

This will remove your class 'icon-plus', then add the class 'icon-minus', followed by inserting the html that you choose to enter.

I've opted to use `.html()` in my example as it gives you the ability to add `<a>` tags or `<p>` tags (or more!), so that your text can have custom css applied (if you've got it)

The other suggestions of using `.text()` are plausible too.

Check the documentation for [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

It all depends on how much control you want over the object you're dealing with and what exactly you want to do with it.

Have a play, try some new stuff out, and have fun! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass) to add a class, [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass) to remove a class, and [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) to change the text. For example:

HTML:

```
<i id="item" class="icon-plus icon-white"> Test 1</i>
```

JS:

```
​$('​​​#item').removeClass('icon-plus').addClass('new-class').text('new  text');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: $('​​​#item') this means select the tag with that id, since that html is generated i cannot add an id i need to select the tag <i>

Comment: If you are playing around with classes it would be safer to use an id (hence my answer). If this is not feasible just change the selector appropriately. For example: `$('#item')` would become `$('.icon-plus')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're searching for every `icon-plus` :

```
var tag = $('i.icon-plus');
tag.removeClass('icon-plus');
tag.addClass('icon-minus');
tag.text('Something else');
```

If you want catch a specific item, you must use `id="myid"`

Answer (score 0):

You should review this page [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for select element. And this [attributes](http://api.jquery.com/category/attributes/) for changing.